# How do I stop a .cmd file from running and delete it from my oc

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, freeze, lag

I downloaded a software yesterday and then installed it and during the installation I was meant to run a .cmd file as admin but anytime I connect my PC to the internet, it starts hanging, lagging and freezing, please help me, what do I do and I don’t want want to lose my files by formatting my OS is windows 10 latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was meant to run a `.cmd`

Why? Is this legitimate? Is this safe or trusted? By the sounds of it, no it is not trusted, in which case your only solution is a clean install. By running untrustworthy software you can no longer guarantee the integrity of your operating system. How about you paste the content of the `.cmd` in question so we can give you a definitive answer. What were you trying to accomplish by running this executable?

Comment: Thanks, the software was a cracked vst for my fl studio, like a plug-in so I ran an authorizer which is the cmd file, I’ll send you the contents of the file

Comment: Your description is enough.

1.) Never download cracked software, not because it is illegal, but because the ONLY reason to develop a crack, is to use it as an attack vector to gain a foothold for malware. Any illegitimate software runs the same risk, and should be avoided if you do not want to keep formatting your computer.

2.) either pay for your software, or search google for "alternative to" or "open source +software role"

3.) Never run executables from non trusted vendors. This includes, and specifically excludes any cracks, keygens, and any warez/torrent delivered executables.

Comment: Thank you, so please what do I do? I don’t want to lose any of my files at all, they are work files and very important

Comment: So backup ONLY your important documents/files, and format your device. There is no other option. By subjecting work documents to malicious files, you are not only endangering your company, but also your employment at that company. I assume they would not be too happy if sensitive data were to land in the wrong hands.

Comment: Ok, so what about backing up softwares?

Comment: I'd argue that you should not need to back up software. Firstly because your attempt at installing software from a non official source is the reason you are in this predicament, and backing up said software will cause you to end in the same scenario.

Comment: Second because there is generally little reason to do so. Whatever software you use these days usually has an account/licence associated with it. All you need is your licence/user details to download the appropriate software from the **OFFICIAL VENDOR ONLY**. If you are thinking this means that you are unable to use certain software any longer, i highly suggest you take a look at: [AlternativeTo](https://alternativeto.net/), failing this, your only choice left is to pay for the licence.
tl;dr; Pay up, use alternative software, or continue to share your OS with malware.